# continuous, two-dimensional function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

I have a question to this two dimensional function.

$f_1(x,y):=\begin{cases} \frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2},&\text{if }(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0,&\text{else}\end{cases}$

I want to analyse if this function is continous for $(x,y)=0$
I think i can show this with an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof

$$|f(x,y)-f(0,0)|=\left|\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}\right|\leq 1$$

Would this be correct for the start? I dont know how to finish the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not continuous, so it is not a good start. First identify the informal reason why it is not continuous. For example if we approach along the $x$-axis, the limit is $0$. If we approach along $x=y$, the limit is $1$.

Comment: :-) That is true.

Comment: @ChamDao I see you're new here, so please read about accepting answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** A very frequently useful tool when the denominator is a relative of $x^2+y^2$ is to use polar coordinates. In our case we get that our function is $2\sin\theta\cos\theta$, which is highly dependent on $\theta$.

Alternately, we can observe that as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis, the limit is $0$, while as $(x,y) \to  (0,0)$ along the line $x=y$, the limit is $1$.

*After* we have discovered *why* the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$, we can if we wish write a formal $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that it is not continuous.

Comment: I already calculated it with polar coordinates. I got that the function is constant and it have to be $\theta\in\{0,\frac12\pi,\pi,\frac32\pi,2\pi\}$ that the function is equal to zero. I dont get your last sentence.

Comment: The function is indeed constant on any line through the origin, with different constants depending on the line that we choose. That shows the function is not continuous at $(0,0)$. One would then proceed to an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof only if explicitly required to do so, since the geometry is clear. For the proof, let $\epsilon=1/3$. Suppose the limit is $b$. No matter how close $(x,y)$ is to $(0,0)$, the function value could be $0$ or it could be $1$, and $b$ cannot be simultaneously within $1/3$ of $0$ and within $1/3$ of $1$.